# How to load HTML with Flash using WebKitGTK?

Tags: c, linux, flash, webkit, gtk

Using Linux, GTK 3, and WebKitGTK, how do I load an HTML file with Flash in a WebKitWebView? I'm successful in opening a common URL like "http://www.google.com", but when I want to open a URL to play a Flash file, the Flash is not displayed in the web view, and it shows "Missing Plugin" instead. How can I load the Flash plugin in WebKitGTK?